# Python dataclass automate ID incrementation in abstract class

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

I want to create a unique ID incrementation for my Python subclasses using the abstract method, but I don't know how to separate each subclass's set of ID values. Here is my code:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from itertools import count


@dataclass
class Basic:
    identifier: int = field(default_factory=count().__next__, init=False)

    def __init_subclass__(cls, **__):
        super().__init_subclass__(**__)
        # cls.identifier: int = field(default_factory=count().__next__, init=False)

class A(Basic):
    pass


class B(Basic):
    pass
```

The id values are shared between subclasses when I want to separate them:

```
>>> import stack
>>> stack.A()
A(identifier=0)
>>> stack.B()
B(identifier=1)
```

Do you know how to solve the problem? I think the `__init_subclass__` is a solution, but I'm unsure how to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataclasses` library does not fit for your use case. Think a data class as a mutable namedtuple with defaults. I recommend implementing concrete classes.

However, if you insist, you can do like the following by defining another decorator which augments an input class before calling the `dataclasses.dataclass()`. (This assumes using Python 3.10 or later.)

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from itertools import count

def dataclass_with_id(cls):
    setattr(cls, 'identifier', field(default_factory=count().__next__, init=False))
    cls.__annotations__['identifier'] = int
    return dataclass(cls)

@dataclass_with_id
class A:
    pass

@dataclass_with_id
class B:
    pass

print(A(), A())
print(B(), B())
```

If you want to do this work in the `__init_subclass__()` of a common base class, you need to hack the internal implementation of the `dataclasses` module. But don't do it because it will be broken for future Python versions.